# CORDOVA 6.0 image path fail

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

So issue appeared when I upgraded from cordova 5.4 to 6.0. Previously during the build all icons were placed in `resources/` folder. Now they're placed in `Images.xcassets/` folder. Locally all works well but when I try to submit my app I get this. Any solutions? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I'm using cordova CLI as I did for he past ~2 years and all was OK with all cordova versions until now. I've looked into docks again, but nothing has really changed when it comes to icons setup in `config.xml` so not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Sorry I don't know *CLI*. I use *Build*. FWIW: *Phonegap Build* is the cloud-based service by Adobe/Phonegap. I change your tag so it is `phonegap-cli` not `phonegap-build`. Your issue might be 6.0. There has been quite a few reports on the [*Phonegap Build* forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)(Nitobi) about this. They don't mention 6.0, but I have my suspicions.  Link to: Cordova [Core Plugins Bugs](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-bugs.md) and by platform. I see no bugs at this time for Android on "icons".

Comment: Try also [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) Best of Luck

Comment: Hmm. wait. I think there might be a bug with `xxxhdpi`. The people at google groups might know. FWIW: I am on that daily.

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650